# Why llvm::FunctionType(Type*, bool) has bool if by definition it doesn't take parameters?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

One definition of `FunctionType *FunctionType::get` is:

```
FunctionType *FunctionType::get(Type *Result, bool  isVarArg)
```

The [documentation](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1FunctionType.html#ab781285a21baf484d3023a63da798fc7) says:

> Create a `FunctionType` taking no parameters.

When are we going to use the `bool isVarArg` parameter to indicate that the number of arguments is variable if the type has no parameters?

Comment: @ggorlen Question updated with the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that variable arguments are treated differently by LLVM than fixed/positional parameters. No *fixed* parameters (the kind that would appear in [`ArrayRef<Type *> llvm::FunctionType::params () const`](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1FunctionType.html#a0400b7a6fcffcd3892d7bb6de435674a)) are what the docs mean by "no parameters", so varargs are exempt.

If you check the note for [`getNumParams()`](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1FunctionType.html#a104d6154321899b53e40455e71d8e83a), it says:

> Return the number of fixed parameters this function type requires. This does not consider varargs.

Comment: So a more accurate documentation would be: "creates a FunctionType taking no fixed/positional parameters". Thanks!